# Pandas remove parts of string after specified character sequence

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I would like to remove a part of a string from a value inside a dataframe, using pandas.

Value:

```
"transaction  DATUM 07.03.2019, 07.48 UHR1.TAN 246915 DATUM 14.10.2019, 09.03 UHR1.TAN 620955 Client Name"
```

What I want is to remove "DATUM 07.03.2019, 07.48 UHR1.TAN 246915 DATUM 14.10.2019, 09.03 UHR1.TAN 620955"

Expected result would be

```
 "transaction Client Name"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use replace function like this.

```py
df["transaction"] = df["transaction"].str.replace(r"(?<=transaction\s).*(?=\sClient)", "")
```

[Here the regex in action](https://regex101.com/r/uSc7M0/1)